# Volume using the shell method

Tags: calculus

The shell radius is $x+4$ and shell height is $\sqrt{x}-x$, the thickness is $dx$.

I have determined that the boundaries are from $0$ to $1$.

$$V=2\pi\int_0^{1}(x+4)(\sqrt{x}-x) dx$$

I simplified the integrand and got

$$V=2\pi \int_0^{1}(x\sqrt{x}-x^2+4\sqrt{x}-4x)dx$$

Now I run into my problem, how would I take the integral of the first and third term? I have not learned the method of integration by parts. What am I missing here?

Comment: $x \sqrt{x} = x^{3/2}$ is a power function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from the 2nd equation (since you have just asserted a bunch of things above that we can't verify), you can integrate each term separately, and they are all of the same form:

$$\int x^p dx = \frac{1}{p+1}x^{p+1}$$

so you have:

$$2\pi\int_0^1 (x^{3/2} -x^2 +4x^{1/2} -4x)dx$$

$$2\pi \left. \left[ \frac{2}{5}x^{5/2} -\frac{1}{3}x^3 +\frac{8}{3}x^{3/2} -2x^2  \right] \right|_0^1$$

$$\frac{22\pi}{15}$$

Answer (score 0):

This is my attempt:
$$V=2\pi \int_0^{1}(x\sqrt{x}-x^2+4\sqrt{x}-4x)dx$$
$$V=2\pi \int_0^{1}(x^{\frac{3}{2}}-x^2+4x^{\frac{1}{2}}-4x)dx$$
$$V=2\pi \int_0^{1}(x^{\frac{3}{2}}-x^2+4x^{\frac{1}{2}}-4x)dx$$
$$V=2\pi\left(\dfrac{x^{\frac{5}{2}}}{\frac{5}2}-\frac{x^3}{3}+\dfrac{4x^{\frac{3}{2}}}{\frac{3}2}-2x^2\right) ^1_0$$
$$V=2\pi\left(\frac{2}{5}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac83-2\right)-\left(0\right)$$
$$V=2\pi\left(\frac{11}{15}\right)$$
$$V=\frac{22π}{15}$$

Comment: You lost the first 4 !

Comment: OH! Thankyou!! I will fix it